# Traversing hashes in Perl based on config

Tags: perl

I need to be able to pluck specific values from data that I receive from different 3rd parties. The data can structured differently depending on the 3rd party. For example:

```
my $first = 
{
    email     => "joe\@example.com",
    firstname => "Joe",
    lastname  => "Regular",
};

my $second =  
{
    user => {
        e-mail    => "joe\@example.com",
        firstName => "Joe",
        lastName  => "Regular",
      }
};
```

I know what the data structure will be for each 3rd party, so I can define that as config. What I want to end up with is

```
my $email = _magic($first_config,$first);
my $other_email = _magic($second_config,$second);
```

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Build a look-up table, party_description => code_to_run. You can use a dispatch table, hash with values being coderefs. (Btw, you show Perl data structures -- how do you "_receive_" that from a 3rd party?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a look-up table. And you can use a *dispatch table*, hash with values being *code references*, so that when a party-identification is used as the key the code for that party executes

```
my %get_value = ( first => \&fetch_first, second => \&fetch_second );

my $party = 'first';  # input via command-line options, STDIN ...

my $email = $get_value{$party}->();
```

where `\&fetch_first` is a reference to the subroutine `fetch_first`. You can also enter it directly, `first => sub { ... }`, suitable for simple code. See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), and [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

There are many ways to carry data in your program, and so to implement the lookup itself.

Here is an illustration, built in steps. It uses the (confirmed) fact that the data is in valid Perl data structures, and for simplicity it specifies the data right in each sub.

```
sub fetch_first {
   my $data = {
       email     => '...',
       firstName => '...',
   };
   return $data->{email};
}
```

This only delivers the email address, but we can do better.

Once you *dereference* a code reference you can also pass arguments

```
my $first_name = $get_value{$party}->('firstName');
```

where the subs are now written to use this input to return the required field

```
sub fetch_first {
    my ($query) = @_;
    my $data = {
       email     => '...',
       firstName => '...',
    };
    return $data->{$query};
}
```

A big weakness of the above is that the calling code must use valid names of keys, so it needs to *know the details of implementation* of what it is using.

This can be improved, for example by choosing an interface for the call which is then translated in the subs into key names (or via yet another look-up structure).  Then you make calls such as

```
my $email = $get_value{$party}->('email');  # or: 'first', 'last'
```

and somewhere you have association `first => 'firstName'` (etc) which subs can look up.

The flexibility is greatly helped by data being set up in a consistent way. The whole thing can also be quite maintainable if the code is organized thoughtfully.

If this grows more complex the solution is to write a class. Then you can build a very nice system.

Comment: Those are valid Perl data structures that I'm getting from decoded JWT tokens using [Crypt::JWT](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::JWT).

Comment: LOL! If I wouldn't have used such a dispatch table myself a few days ago, I wouldn't have noticed.

Comment: @BetterDeal OK -- that helps, if they don't "evolve" (change without notice over time or some such).  If the lowest level "identifiers" -- keys in your example -- are consistent you can build a really nice system.   I'd suggest to first give it a little thought, in the first place on how to store data.  It needn't be spelled out in each sub.

Comment: @BetterDeal  I had a typo there (`\%...` instead of `\&...`), which would make it fail miserably. Just a note in case you didn't notice the chage (fixed).

Comment: Thanks heaps, @zdim much appreciated :)

I've used a dispatch table, as you suggested.

Comment: @BetterDeal Great :)  Let me know if questions pop up. Note that has a lot of room for adjustment and further learning.  For one, it seems to be a nice way to get going with OO, either Perl's own or [Moo](http://search.cpan.org/~haarg/Moo-2.003002/lib/Moo.pm) (a light-weight sibling of the great big [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Moose-2.2005/lib/Moose.pm)).  Even if it is not necessary (for small and well formed data sets) once you wish to look at OO this may be a good starting point.